# SQL case statement closest to current date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need help create a case statement to find the closest date from date table. My data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vWUu.jpg

I basically want to set:

Y flag if it's closest to today's date from a.FROM_EFFDT and is not null.
F if to_effdate is null
else N

```
         WHEN a.FROM_EFFDT < GETDATE() AND (to_effdate) IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' 
         WHEN to_effdate IS NULL THEN 'F' 
         ELSE 'N'
```

Comment: Doesn't this code work?

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately. It's setting every row to Y flag.

Comment: Can you explain more the *closest to today's date* part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
(case when row_number() over (order by abs(datediff(day, getdate(), to_effdate)) = 1
      then 'Y'
      when to_effdate is null then 'F'
      else 'N'
 end)
```

Comment: Thanks. Modified script in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to accomplish it with something like this.  Though this isn't bulletproof, you could get duplicates if the closest date is tied.

```
create table Dates (from_effdt datetime, to_effdt datetime, flag varchar(1))

insert Dates (from_effdt, to_effdt, flag)
values
('2019-03-16', null, '') ,
('2018-06-14', '2019-03-16', '') ,
('2018-05-14', '2018-06-14', '') ,
('2018-01-01', '2018-05-14', '') 

select * from Dates

UPDATE Dates
SET flag = 
CASE 
WHEN from_effdt = (
    select top 1 from_effdt
    from Dates
    order by ABS ( DATEDIFF(day, from_effdt, getdate()) )
)
THEN 'Y'
ELSE
    'N'
END
```

*update, not sure why I created it as an update.  This select should do.

```
SELECT from_effdt, to_effdt,
CASE 
WHEN from_effdt = (
    select top 1 from_effdt
    from Dates
    order by ABS ( DATEDIFF(day, from_effdt, getdate()) )
)
THEN 'Y'
ELSE
    'N'
END [numberOfDaysAway]
FROM Dates
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
CASE 
WHEN from_effdt = (
    select from_effdt
      from Dates
      where abs(datediff(second, from_effdt, getdate()))
        = (select min(
        abs(datediff(second, from_effdt, getdate()))
)
from Dates)
)
THEN 'Y'
ELSE
    'N'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition by id order by to_effdt desc)
,id
,from_effdt
,to_effdt
, CASE WHEN (ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition by id order by to_effdt desc) = 1) THEN ('Y')
       WHEN (to_effdt IS NULL) THEN ('F') ELSE ('N') End as flag
from a
```